# _nextafterf on Visual C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I need to use the function _nextafterf on Visual C++ 32 bit to compute the distance in ULP of some results compare to reference functions.

C99 provides nextafterf and nextafter for float and double but these functions are not supported by Visual C++. However, Visual C++ 2010 supports _nextafterf and nextafter from  but only in 64 bits... With the 32 bits model only _nextafter is support and from ...

Is there a way to get _nextafterf working on Visual Studio maybe up to Visual C++ 2005?

Thanks,
Christophe

Comment: Don't know about C++. I've heard that Visual Studio C compiler is not a C99 compiler. So, if you need C99 features, switch compilers (or make pressure with your compiler maker to include the features you want in the next version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always implement it...

https://www.google.com/search?q=libm%2Fsrc%2Fs_nextafterf.c

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Code Search no longer exists. This answer is no longer of much help.

Comment: @Slavik81 - You can use code.ohloh.net (formerly koders.com). My only complaint is that you have to copy and paste to get the URL of a project. http://code.ohloh.net/search?s=nextafterf.c leads to https://github.com/cloudius-systems/osv/blob/master/libc/math/nextafterf.c (and that dir contains a lot of other math functions). From the commit info, it appears that this file is from musl, which uses the MIT license: http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/COPYRIGHT

Answer (score 3):

There is a templatized equivalent `nextafter` in Boost.Math, see [Finding the Next Representable Value in a Specific Direction (nextafter)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/utils/next_float/nextafter.html).

> The C99 functions must use suffixes f
>   and l to distinguish float and long
>   double versions. C++ uses the template
>   mechanism instead.

Answer (score 0):

found a code here:

```
/*
 *  nextafterf.c
 *  cLibm
 *
 *  Created by Ian Ollmann on 6/14/07.
 *  Copyright 2007 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 */
...
float nextafterf( float x, float y )
{
union{ float f; uint32_t u;} ux = { x };
uint32_t    step = 1;

if( y != y || x != x)
    return x + y;

if( y <= x ) // a subtraction here would risk Inf-Inf
{
    if( y == x )
        return y;   //make sure sign of 0 is correct

    step = -1;
}

//correct for the sign
int32_t signMask = (int32_t) ux.u >> 31;
step = (step ^ signMask) - signMask;

uint32_t absux = ux.u & 0x7fffffffU;

if( absux == 0 )                // zero
{
    ux.f = y;
    ux.u = (ux.u & 0x80000000U) + 1U;
    return ux.f;
}

ux.u += step;
return ux.f;
}
```

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libm/Libm-315/Source/ARM/nextafterf.c

work?